# Dapper: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, sqlite, dapper

i am using Dapper for accessing sqlite database and getting 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'. Any help is appreciated.

```
// Create table schema
CREATE TABLE "mytable" ( "field1"   TEXT, "field2"  TEXT, "field3"  TEXT, 
                         "field4"   TEXT, "field5"  TEXT, 
                         "field6"   bit, 
                         "field7"   TEXT, "field8"  TEXT, "field9"  TEXT,
                         "field10"  TEXT, 
                         "field11"  DateTime )
```

Query code :

```
var result= sqliteConnection.Query<TestItem>("Select * from mytable");
```

Query to insert data:

```
INSERT INTO "main"."mytable" ("field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5", "field6", "field7", "field8", "field9", "field10", "field11") VALUES ('750eb223-2993-4d85-9d4f-3e8689e9baa7', 'some value', '', 'some value', 'some value', '1', '84', 'ae35e1e1-dd4c-4e49-a76c-d577f417bf9a', 'some value', 'HOME.aspx', 
                             '2020/01/20 17:38');
INSERT INTO "main"."mytable" ("field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5", "field6", "field7", "field8", "field9", "field10", "field11") VALUES ('750eb223-2993-4d85-9d4f-3e8689e9baa7', 'some value', 'asdf', 'some value', 'some value', '1', '32', 'a1cd1b8f-95f6-4b03-8d54-f904c21749ac', 'HOME.aspx', 'HOME.aspx', 
                              '2020/01/20 17:38');
INSERT INTO "main"."mytable" ("field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5", "field6", "field7", "field8", "field9", "field10", "field11") VALUES ('750eb223-2993-4d85-9d4f-3e8689e9baa7', 'some value', 'some value', 'some value', 'some value', '1', '99', 'b9e63bfd-c73e-4e9a-b3e7-30ae49d8a002', 'CALLSS.aspx', 'CALLSS.aspx', 
                              '2020/01/20 17:38');
```

Error Message:

```
Error parsing column 10 (field11=HOME.aspx - String)
```

Inner Exception Message:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

StackTrace:

```
at Dapper.SqlMapper.ThrowDataException(Exception ex, Int32 index, IDataReader reader, Object value) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 3609
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryImpl>d__138`1.MoveNext() in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 1100
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 723
   at Tzunami.LinkResolver.DatabaseMigration.Models.DBMigrator.<MigrateDeploymentListItemAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Users\surendra\source\repos\Tzunami.LinkResolver.MigrationTool\Tzunami.LinkResolver.DatabaseMigration\Models\DBMigrator.cs:line 77
```

Mapping item class:

```
public class TestItem
{
  public string Field1 { get; set; }
  public string Field2 { get; set; }
  public string Field3 { get; set; }
  public string Field4 { get; set; }
  public string Field5 { get; set; }
  public string Field6 { get; set; }
  public string Field7 { get; set; }
  public string Field8 { get; set; }
  public string Field9 { get; set; }
  public string Field10 { get; set; }
  public string Field11 { get; set; }
}
```

Database schema and entries can be seen from following example taken from DB SQLite browser
[image]

[image]

Comment: It is quite strange Issue if data format was wrong in table, how can it can be easily get from reader and parsed i think there is some issue with dapper connection.Query() method itself.

Comment: Do you able to insert using the SQLite browser ?

Comment: Yeah it is inserted  from db browser and it recognize that field as text/numeric.

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` statement says this field should be treated as a `DateTime` but those strings can't be handled that way. When Dapper runs, it sees that it has to load this `DateTime` field and format the values into strings. When it tries to simply load the values as dates though (that's what the database says they are), the operation fails. You have to either change the values or the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly: Keep in mind that as mentioned in  Sqlite Documentation there is no `Datatypes` as `DateTime` it is stored as a text or some numbers somehow so its better to save dates as plain text during DB cretion.
Documentation here: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Secondly: It is Expected DateTime to be on  ISO8601 format i.e. "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS" format but as data on table it is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM" it cant be parsed as a `DateTime`.

**Workaround:**

As You can't Change DB schema and data,  `connection.ExecuteReader` works quite well on these circumstances, so use  `connection.ExecuteReader` and to get column value as string use `reader.GetString()` Method.

Comment: what should i do then? The table is already created and could not be altered now. How can I retrive data without making any changes to the database?

Comment: it is quite strange kind of issue if data format was wrong in table how can it can be easily get from reader and parsed i think there is some issue with dapper connection.Query() method itself.

Comment: @SurendraShrestha the docs explain you should use the ISO8601 format, ie `YYYY-MM-DD ...`. Don't use localized formats. If you use ISO8601 the provider will translate it to DateTime

Comment: Thanks @PashupatiKhanal it seems, in the current scenario, it would be best to use the ExecuteReader method (since dapper does not seem to handle this) and manually retrieve the datetime property and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I never used SQLite but as per [document](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), SQLite does not have datatype to store `DateTime`.

> **2.2. Date and Time Datatype**
>   SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> - TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

Considering above, your date format in following code:

> `INSERT INTO "main"."mytable" (..., "field11") VALUES (..., '2020/01/20 17:38');`

should be

> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS

This way, you do not need to change the database schema; just a change in your code.

Comment: Thanks @AmitJoshi. It does seem that the while saving the data in the database the date time format is not correct. Since I could not use dapper auto mapping. I used execute reader method and manually use DateTime.ParseExact to extract the date information

Answer (score 0):

Try with this format as string.

> '2007-01-01 10:00:00'

i.e. yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: The table and the rows are already there and cannot be changed, all i want is to is get data from the table without modifying any fields and use that information in other parts

Comment: @SurendraShrestha Can you show us how the data is represented in sqllite. So if i understand correctly. You are able to insert the above values from sqllite directly and its not able to do from dapper ?

Comment: I have updated my question to include the screenshots of the table structure and data using DB SQLite browser

Comment: @SurendraShrestha the rows will have to be changed if you want SQLite to treat them as dates. Otherwise you'll have to read the field as a string and parse it on the client.